# Send an email with Outlook without a subject --- dialog box issue

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am using the following code to send emails using Outlook:

```cs
    private static void SendMailItem(string from, string to, string subject, string body, string attachment = null)
    {
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
      mailItem.Subject = subject;
      mailItem.To = to;
      mailItem.Body = body;
      if (attachment != null)
      {
        mailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue);
      }
      mailItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
      mailItem.Display(false);
      mailItem.Send();
    }
```

It works almost perfectly, but I run into a problem when trying to send an email **without a subject**. The following dialog box pops up:

[image]

**I want to skip this prompt or automatically accept (send anyway)**. How do I achieve this?

Comment: `app.DisplayAlerts = false` is the way to stop other Office apps showing dialogs during automation, don't know if that works for Outlook though. Probably worth trying.

Comment: Is there is any specific reason your are using this way instead of SMTP ?

Comment: @stuartd - Outlook.Application object does not expose the DisplayAlerts property.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I thought it might not. BTW I was a very happy Redemption user many years ago :)

Comment: @WamiqRehman yes I have reasons for using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` over `System.Net.Mail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the `mailItem.Display(false);` line.

Comment: This was the correct solution---I misunderstood what `mailItem.Display(false)` would do, I thought I needed it to prevent dialog boxes/windows/etc. from showing. Turned out to be the opposite!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can specify the `Subject` line. Make sure the string is not empty or null.
2. Or just send the item without displaying it:

```
private static void SendMailItem(string from, string to, string subject, string body, string attachment = null)
   {
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
     mailItem.Subject = subject;
     mailItem.To = to;
     mailItem.Body = body;
     if (attachment != null)
     {
       mailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue);
     }
     mailItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;   
     mailItem.Send();
   }
```

Be aware, you may get Outlook security prompts while automating Outlook. The Outlook object model includes entry points to access Outlook data, save data to specified locations, and send emails. These entry points are available to legitimate and malicious application developers alike. Versions of Outlook 98 and Outlook 2000 applied with the Outlook Email Security Update, and all subsequent versions starting from Outlook 2000 SP2 use the Object Model Guard to help protect users.

The Object Model Guard warns users and prompts users for confirmation when untrusted applications attempt to use the object model to obtain email address information, store data outside of Outlook, execute certain actions, and send email messages. Although the Object Model Guard succeeds in identifying and protecting these entry points, two main issues exist that render the Object Model Guard rather unpractical:

The default circumstances that applications invoke the Object Model Guard in earlier versions of Outlook can result in excessive security prompting for legitimate applications.

The limitations of COM and Windows in identifying the specific application that is invoking the Object Model Guard have made it difficult for users to respond to the security prompts with certainty.

For more information on the various security prompts of the Object Model Guard, see [Outlook Object Model Security Warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/outlook-object-model-security-warnings). For more information on the protected object model entry points, see [Protected Properties and Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/protected-properties-and-methods).

To avoid security prompts you can use:

1. [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/object-model-guard.php) which allows turning security prompts off on the fly.
2. A low-level API (Extended MAPI) which doesn't trigger security prompts. Or just any wrapper around that API such as Redemption.
3. Deploy Outlook security settings (for administrators).